# Applozic ConversationActivity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, applozic

I want to add Applozic CoversationActivity to Navigation Drawer as Fragment. Do you think it is possible?

Comment: If it's an `Activity` subclass, then no.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can add the fragment to your Navigation Drawer you can check this link
[Applozic Fragment support doc](https://docs.applozic.com/docs/android-chat-theme-and-customization#section-adding-chat-fragment-to-your-activity) for adding MobiComQuickConversationFragment.java fragment to your Navigation Drawer item
In that above link check first option **Adding Chat fragments to Activity**